# Debug.Log not being written to the player.log after the beginning of a Build play time

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging

I am using Unity to develop my game and I am running in some problems with debugging my builds.

I have been trying to find the reason why my Debug.log commands don't seem to be written on my player.log file during my builds. In my editor it works fine, but in the build it runs until a certain point and then it does not log anything else. I am trying to solve this problem for sometime, since I am having some other problems that occur only in my builds and not in the editor and I was trying to debug them.

It seems like anything in the Awake method at the first frame of the game is debugged correctly according to my test, anything past the first frame does not get logged.

I am running a little bit low on hope for this issue, since I made a post on Unity Forums in October 2023 and didn't got a single response. I just let this slip and solve other problems in the game, but now I need to solve this no matter what. Any help or insight will be appreciated.

Here is a print from my build settings:

[Build Settings Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyPCO.png)

I tried unchecking the Autoconnect Profiler and the Script Debugging options to see if anything would change but nothing changed.

My Unity version is 2021.3.2f1. My PC is a 16gb RAM / RTX 3060/ AMD Ryzen 7 5700 G.

Comment: Are you using any code at all that is not yours and that might bring in any logging plugin? That sounds like there is another logger (possibly writing to some other location then you expect) set up.

Comment: That is possible. I tried disabling an old debugger one of my old employes used on the project. The name of the script is DebugLogManager, but even after disabling it the problem still persists. I gonna try to search for anything that could interfere with log placement.

Comment: Can an exception not be catched by the console / logger and make the logs to stop being logged into the player.logs? I deleted the plugging and check for any "Console.SetOut", "Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded" and "Application.logMessageReceived" (usually functions used to reroute logs) and found nothing.

The last possibility I see right now is some exception causing all this to happen, if that is even possible. Otherwise, is back to the drawing board. Only problem is that I will probably need to try catch about 200 different scripts. May god rest my soul.